# Como conseguir documentação das DLL's do Windows 7?

Tags: windows, dll, documentação, windows-7

Onde consigo uma documentação completa do funcionamento e de como usar as funções/procedures das DLL's do Windows 7?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Toda documentação deste tipo fica no [Docs Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Especificamente a [API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O principal do [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).